# Проверить символ добавляемой строки на принадлежность к списку

Tags: javascript

В текстовое поле `inputAddLabel` вводится какой-то символ. При нажатии на кнопку `Добавить метку`  срабатывает событие `pushLabel()`. Однако должен добавляться не любой символ, а только тот, который содержится в `listAlphabet`. Т.е. должна выполниться проверка на принадлежность добавляемой метки к алфавиту.

```js
function pushAlphabet() {
    var alph = document.getElementById("inputAddAlphabet").value;
    if(alph.length == 1){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = alph + " ";
        document.getElementById("listAlphabet").appendChild(li);

    } else { alert('Вы можете добавить только один символ!');}
}

function pushLabel() {
    var label = document.getElementById("inputAddLabel").value;
    console.log("label", label);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = label + " ";
    document.getElementById("listLabels").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
   <div class="alphabet">
        <label>Алфавит</label>
        <form>
            <input id="inputAddAlphabet" type="text">
            <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushAlphabet()">
        </form>
        <ul id="listAlphabet"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="labels">
        <label>Метки</label>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="inputAddLabel">
            <input type="button" value="Добавить метку" onclick="pushLabel()">
        </form>
        <ul id="listLabels"></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: У вас какая-то чепуха в коде

Comment: почему? как правильно тогда?

Comment: Наченм с того что элемент listStates не имеет свойства value

Comment: я не понимаю, как указать на то, что мне необходимо сравнивать с элементами из списка listStates

Comment: воспользуйся парсером

Answer (score 3):

Задача не совсем ясна, но вот пример:

```js
var frm,
    listEl;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  frm = document.forms['add-state'];
  listEl = document.getElementById('states-list');
  frm.addEventListener('submit', pushState);
});

function pushState(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let iSt = frm['initial-state'].value.toLowerCase();
  if (!iSt.length)
    return;
  let items = listEl.querySelectorAll('li');
  for (let item of items) {
    if (item.textContent.toLowerCase() === iSt) {
      alert('OK');
      return;
    }
  }
  let newLi = document.createElement('li');
  newLi.textContent = iSt;
  listEl.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```css
body,
#add-state { font: 14px sans-serif; }

#add-state {
  display: flex; align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 10px; padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#add-state input,
#add-state button {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#add-state > button[type="submit"] {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<form id="add-state" name="add-state" action="return false;">
  <label>Начальное состояние:<br><input type="text" name="initial-state"></label>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Добавить состояние</button>
</form>
<ul id="states-list"></ul>
```

Comment: задача немного в другом состоит. начальное состояние  добавляется не в listStates,  а  отдельно в текстовое поле вводится значение и выдается сообщение о том, принадлежит ли это значение к listStates или нет

Comment: проверка происходит в отдельной функции, не в функции добавления элемента в список

Comment: @vita_run, _"задача немного в другом состоит ..."_ - в таком случае, дополните ваш вопрос этой информацией (другие отвечающие могут не заметить ее в комментариях). Также уточните, что именно Вы подразумеваете под фразой "добавляется значение" (добавляется *как* и *когда*?) + когда именно должна выполняться проверка вхождения в список: по какому действию/событию... это тоже напишите в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: отредактировала описание задачи. Надеюсь, стало понятно что требуется сделать.